# how to close google chrome and have it save your tabs

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

When my computer shuts down due to automatic updates and I restart it all the tabs I had open are restored. But when I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> all the tabs are lost.

Is there a way to have my tabs saved when I manually close Google Chrome? Or should I just kill every single instance of it in the Task Manager or something?

Comment: `Ctrl + Shift + Q`, or `Exit` from the RH dropdown menu now works with _Continue where you left off_. If selecting _Close all windows_ from the taskbar, only one tabbed group is saved. But the others can be pulled from the history menu, provided the number of tabs in those groups differ  to the one just loaded. Else good luck with that. :P

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In the settings, there is an option that says "Continue where you left off" under "On Startup" option. That should keep your tabs intact when you close and launch chrome every time.

This will work for both the hotkey and manual close.

Comment: This does not work if you close Chrome from the taskbar in Windows 10.  Only a single tabgroup is restored the next time you launch.  Very annoying/

Answer (score 2):

**On a Mac** (MacBook Pro)
Use the "command --> Q" shortcut or click on your screen's top-left menu option "Chrome --> Quit Google Chrome" or from your Dock (typically at the bottom of your screen) right-click on the Chrome icon then choose Quit.  Any of these will preserve your tabs.  That is... if you have already selected the Chrome option to 'Continue Where I Left Off'.

Using the Red 'X' icon at the top-left of your Chrome browser window, to close the browser, will not preserve the tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Mac

You need to select Quit Google Chrome from the dropdown menu and the next time you open up the browser your tabs will be in tact.  When you use the hotkeys it doesn't work.

Mac & PC

Go to settings and under On Startup select 'Continue Where I Left Off'

Comment: There's not a "Quit Google Chrome" option. Perhaps you mean "Exit" but that doesn't save my tabs either.

Comment: @neubert He's on a Mac, it could be different there.

Answer (score 0):

The latest versions of Chrome automatically save your most recently closed tabs.

[image: Example Image]

I have also verified that this works when using the Ctrl + Shift + Q command.

This process is much better than using "Continue where you left off".  Because if you actually do want to close all the tabs you do not have to close them all one by one.