# How to easily kill the Google Chrome main process (Windows 7 / Ubuntu Linux)

Tags: windows-7, linux, google-chrome, process, kill

I like Chrome's feature that lets me restore its pages after it's been closed ungracefully. I use that as a way to save my session (e.g. when just rebooting to install OS updates).

What I've been doing until now:

- Open Chrome's Task Manager, look for the Browser process and remember the PID.
- kill the process with that PID (with `kill -9 <pid>` in Ubuntu and with the task manager in Windows)

I'm looking for a way to do that in just one click, or as few actions as possible. E.g. with a script that I put on my desktop.

I'm looking for a solution both for Windows 7 and Ubuntu Linux.

*Note:* I know I could use some session-management Chrome extension instead, but I've tried some of those and they don't work exactly [like I want](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/38721), whereas the method described above works exactly like I want, but is a bit too difficult to use.

*Note:* On both Linux and Windows all my Chrome processes have the name `chrome`, so I can't differentiate between tab processes and the browser process by name. I'm saying this because I've seen [advice](https://askubuntu.com/a/445035/111033) to kill the process called `google-chrome-stable` - I don't have such a process.

**Edit:** I found [this answer on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/878835) which works very well without the need for an killing any processes. I've voted to close my question as a duplicate.

Comment: Why don't you just download a session saver extension?

Comment: @DrZoo: I haven't yet found an extension that works the way I've described in [this question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/38721)

Comment: That’s easy: It’s the Chrome process that doesn’t have a Chrome process as its parent. I’m too lazy to try and write some script now. On Linux you can probably use `/proc` and on Windows perhaps `wmic` or something. Or just write a proper program.

Comment: @monov Session Buddy.

Answer (score 1):

Simply type:

```
killall google-chrome-stable
```

Update after monov's edit:

To kill a tab process:
In chromium (I believe in chrome the processes will have similar flags) tab processes are flagged with type=renderer. So in the one-liner below, after listing those processses and extracting PID's, the line number in sed pipe defines the tab number and the nth PID is killed:

```
ps aux | grep chrome | grep -v grep | grep type=renderer | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f2 | sed -n 3p | xargs -i kill -9 {}
```

To kill the xth browser window (the parent process with no flag or additional info after "chrome"). Note that all other processes do not end with "chrome"

```
ps aux | grep chrome$ | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f2 | sed -n 3p | xargs -i kill -9 {}
```

Note: pgrep couldn't return the same answer with end of line ($) regex matching, so I used grep.

If the detailed info in tab process in chrome differs from that in chromium, please let me know.

Comment: I just added an edit to my question about this. Please see it.

Comment: Thanks, but your solutions are for "killing a tab process" and "killing the xth browser window". I want to kill the main browser process instead - the one that owns all the windows and all the tabs. There's never more than one such process.